# How to check value of character in golang with UTF-8 strings?

Tags: string, go, utf-8

I'm attempting to check if the first character in a string matches the following, note the UTF-8 quote characters:

```
c := t.Content[0]
if c != '.' && c != ',' && c != '?' && c != '“' && c != '”'{
```

This code does not work due to the special characters in the last two checks.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is `t.Content` of type `string`?

Comment: The `Content[0]` access the first _byte_ not the first character/codepoint/rune. In UTF-8 runes may be represented by more than one byte. Either convert your string to a rune slice (`[]rune(t.Content)`) or work with unicode/utf8/DecodeRuneInString and releated functions.

Comment: Wow, a "rune slice". I didn't know about that one, that would also have solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indexing a `string` indexes its bytes (in UTF-8 encoding - this is how Go stores strings in memory), but you want to test the first character.

So you should get the first `rune` and not the first `byte`. For efficiency you may use [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRuneInString) which only decodes the first `rune`. If you need all the runes of the `string`, you may use type conversion like `all := []rune("I'm a string")`.

See this example:

```
for _, s := range []string{"asdf", ".asdf", "”asdf"} {
    c, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
    if c != '.' && c != ',' && c != '?' && c != '“' && c != '”' {
        fmt.Println("Ok:", s)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not ok:", s)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3MMYsPP8MN)):

```
Ok: asdf
Not ok: .asdf
Not ok: ”asdf
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @icza's great answer: It's worth noting that while indexing of strings is in bytes, `range` of strings is in runes. So the following also works:

```
for _, s := range []string{"asdf", ".asdf", "”asdf"} {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c != '.' && c != ',' && c != '?' && c != '“' && c != '”' {
            fmt.Println("Ok:", s)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Not ok:", s)
        }
        break // we break after the first character regardless
    }
}
```